# Release ImageView background resources in android

Tags: android, imageview

i am using some ImageView in XML file and setting backgroundResources of them.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anim0image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="115px"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"       
    android:background="@drawable/small_gray"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anim1image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160px"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px"
    android:background="@drawable/small_gray"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Now i am changing background resources from codding. like this :

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_red);
```

Now when i exit from this screen and enter again it show me red image. but i want to show default image (which i use in XML file). So Please tell me that how can i release red image so that we screen again loads it sets imageview with default image.

Thanks.

Comment: When are you changing the image resource?? in any click event?

Comment: using a Timer for changing Image Resources. changing in every second.

Comment: Try to re-set the ImageView to use the "small_gray"on the "onResume"
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_gray);
 method, or finish the screen on the "onPause" method to gurantee that when we get back to the screen your ImageView will be re-inirialized.

void onPause(){
  this.finish();
}

Comment: @Eslam Yousef :  i set default ImageView resources in xml file.

Comment: ok, but you changed it somewhere on the code, so, you need to re-set it again when resuming the screen, or destroying the screen in order to being initialized again with the value in the XML file when revisiting it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the background of the images fully programmatically.

If you do it like the code you posted, every time you open your app, you call `onCreate` method and you will `setContentView` (load your layout) again with the grey values.

One way is to use `SharedPrefferences` to store the color value every time you change it, and when you open your app you check the `SharedPrefferences` for the color.

If `SharedPrefferences` are `null`, means there is no color change and you set the default grey color. If there is a color stored, take it and set it to the image/images you need.

Hope it helps! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add below methods.

```
@override
protected void onPause()
{
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(null);
}

@override
protected void onResume()
{
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_gray);
}
```

You need to reset the imageview while exiting from activity and again at the time of resuming you need to set defalt image. So above two call back methods will accomplish your aim.